# Find the closest point of a complex navmesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to imagine which approach to use to solve this question.
I have a navmesh built on numerous levels and at runtime I should find the point closest to the mouse click.

[image]

The aim is to move an object along the navmesh but by clicking anywhere on the screen and not just on the planes (in this case it would be quite simple).
If the navmesh were all on the same Y axis I could easily use `NavMesh.SamplePosition` but this is not the case.
I thought of creating an infinite plane that follows the mouse movement (and use `plane.Raycast` combined with `SamplePosition` but this solution is not applicable as it is not possible to determine the value of the Y axis for the plane during the movement of the cursor.
How would you deal with this problem?

edit:

```
void Update() {
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
      // the following lines return camera position
      Debug.Log(myCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));

      // here I assign the camera's Z axis to Vector3
      Vector3 worldPos = Input.mousePosition;
      worldPos = new Vector3(worldPos.x, worldPos.y, myCam.transform.position.z);
      Debug.Log(myCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(worldPos));
   }
}
```

In the second case, as said in the comment, if I place an object at a certain coordinate I don't get the same value by clicking with the cursor near / above it.

Comment: I don't know much about NavMesh, but maybe Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) would help?

Comment: Maybe these links will help: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.SamplePosition.html

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work because the value of the Z axis is missing ... working on a plane would be all simpler, the raycast would find the depth by itself ... for this reason I thought to attach an infinite plane to the cursor (or otherwise create it in the click position), but also in this case doesn't would work

Comment: Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint returns a point in 3d space with x, y, and z coordinates

Comment: Maybe something is missing me...
myCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) it returns 0, 0, -10 (camera position). Instead assigning to the Vector3 "mousePosition" the value of the Z axis of the camera the x and y axes take values other than zero but they obviously change with each new value that is assigned to Z. While I move the mouse on the screen, without being able to make a raycast of a plane , I can't know what value Z should have at a certain cursor position...

Comment: As a test I positioned a sphere in the scene, say 1, 1, 10 but clicking with the mouse close to it I do not get in any way these coordinates with ScreenToWorldPoint because the Z axis to be modified for Input.mousePosition is not known. Maybe I'm getting lost?

Comment: Post code with ScreenToWorldPoint and screenshot of setup that gives bad values?

Comment: I edited the post with an example.

Comment: The first ScreenToWorldPoint looks good. I don't understand the second one. One limitation of ScreenToWorldPoint is that the objects must have colliders IIRC. Make sure that the camera is not inside a collider. Can you next post a screenshot of the in-game view and a screenshot of the scene view with everything in the scene selected (Ctrl a), camera visible? This can help determine if some colliders are in the way.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "must have a collider"? The planes have colliders but as mentioned no problem by clicking on them. I have to click outside the floors, in the Skybox, where there are no colliders and from that position in space find the closest point of Navmesh ... did I explain myself wrong or did I not understand what you said?

Comment: Oh ok, that changes things, I think I understand the problem. Would it be possible to make a "floor" right under the navmesh, containing a collider but no visuals? That would make the camera ScreenToWorldPoint work. You could change the layer so that it doesn't collide with the player or other objects.